# Using localStorage for pagecount hits

Tags: javascript

For the life of me I can’t figure this out grrr and wondering if someone could help…

My son is doing some html homework. We’re trying to put a page counter that will count and display the number of hits to a page. He’s got an index and three other pages. I’ve put this on each page:

```
<div class="page-count">
  <script type="text/javascript">
      if (localStorage.pagecount)
        {
        localStorage.pagecount=Number(localStorage.pagecount) +1;
        }
    else
      {
        localStorage.pagecount=1;
        }
    document.write("You've had "+ localStorage.pagecount + " hits.");
  </script>
</div>
```

Problem is it counts all of the hits together rather than how many hits per page… how could I get this to count the hits on a single page rather than how many hits in total?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how about keeping separate counters? i.e. `localStorage.page1.pagecount, localStorage.page2.pagecount`, etc - each HTML file will load and store a different variable to/from localstorage

Answer (score 2):

`localStorage` is domain wide and its values are shared across your entire site, not just one page on that site.  `localStorage` values are also only kept in users' browsers and not on the server hosting your website.  Keep this in mind if you are building a page counter.

If you use `localStorage` to keep count, you will only be keeping count of a particular user's visits to that page from a specific computer.

If this is indeed the functionality you are looking for, you can make it work by giving each of your individual pages a separate key within the `pagecount` object.

Something like:

```
// If this is the first time someone has visited your site, you want 
// to check to see if pagecount has been defined.  If not, define the pagecount object.
!localStorage.pagecount ? localStorage.pagecount = {} : '';

var currentPage = window.location.href;
if(localStorage.pagecount[currentPage]){
    localStorage.pagecount[currentPage] = Number(localStorage.pagecount[currentPage]) + 1;
}
else{
    localStorage.pagecount[currentPage] = 1;
}
```

The above gives your `pagecount` object a key for every page that exists on your site.

Answer (score 1):

Because `localStorage` works across all pages under the same domain they will count the same number.

If you'd like to differentiate them you could try something like this:

```
var url_segment = window.location.href.split('/');
var script_name = url_segment[url_segment.length - 1];
if (localStorage[script_name]) {
    localStorage[script_name] = parseInt(localStorage[script_name]) + 1;
}
else {
    localStorage[script_name] = 1;
}

document.write("You've had "+ localStorage[script_name] + " hits.");
```

Note that I did not want to use the entire path as my key, only my script name. You can most likely use the entire path, I just thought this was prettier.